# How to implement a last_modified_by (person) attribute on two unrelated models - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have a `Record` model and in order to edit this model, you must be logged in as an instance of `Admin`. I would like to have a column called `last_modified_by` which points to the Admin who last modified the Record. In the database, I was thinking it would be good in the `records` table to add a column that holds the Admin's `id`; however, the only way I know how to do that is with an association. These two models are not associated with each other so an association doesn't make a lot of sense. Is there any other way I might be able to accomplish this task without resorting to associations? Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I think the association is a good tool here. You might want to try to hack it somehow but I think nothing you can conjure up will ever be as good as an association via a foreign_key(also so fast). But perhaps you would like to name your association and do something like:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :culprit, :class_name => 'Admin', :foreign_key => 'last_modified_by'
end
```

or give it some more senseful naming?

Comment: I too believe the association is the right way here, at it makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Active Record before_save callback.  The callback would save the admin's id into the last_modified_column.  This would make sure the admin id is saved/updated each time there is a change to the model.

For example, assuming admin is @admin:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :save_last_modified

  def save_last_modified
    self.last_modified_column = @admin.id
  end
```

As for getting @admin, you could employ a [method similar to this](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models), and set @admin = Admin.current (like User.current in the link) somewhere in the Record model.

Comment: That was my initial approach but the problem is where do you get the @admin instance from. That method is in the model so it doesn't have access to the current admin.

Comment: [Here is a method](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/47-fetch-current-user-in-models) for storing instance variables and fetching them in models

Comment: @Kelly both of your links are dead